# Android FlowLayout as RecyclerView LayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, flowlayout, recyclerview-layout

I want to implement a Tag Cloud with Android Chips.

[image]

But i think the best way to do this is with a RecycleView and a custom LayoutManager.
I search for a LayoutManager which layout its children like a FlowLayout but found nothing.

Has someone found this kind of behavior or a good and simple tutorial about custom layout managers? I found no simple or simple but incomplete articles.

[image].

Comment: do you want something like https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView

Comment: checkout this https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks AmitVaghela and Bhoomi for your links. Your links point to a standalone ViewGroup. I want the layouting inside of a LayoutManager. I think the inbuild behavior of animations and view recycling is a benefit.

Answer (score 11):

I found a library that does this.

You have add this line to your Gradle depencencies:

```
compile 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'
```

and set your recycler view layout manager with it:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new FlowLayoutManager());
```

You have additional details on how to configure it on Github: https://github.com/xiaofeng-han/AndroidLibs/tree/master/flowlayoutmanager

Comment: Yes, this is good, and worked fine, but how can I use this library for older versions e.g. earlier APIs/SDK before 16, because it need minimum SDK 16, but I want to apply it on SDK 11 too, how it be possible.

Comment: I had to call `.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)` on the manager,  then it works great!

Answer (score 5):

You may try [my library](https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager). See github description page for detailed features/usage.

It provides behavior which exactly you want. 
Its min sdk is 15, which covers almost all nowadays devices being used.

Also it is still maintained, so you can receive additional support from me

Comment: Uff, unfortunately, filling or even centering the contents on fill view is not possible, issues are being ignored since 2019, so I guess it's not maintained, anymore.